# Send Slack Alerts when APIs from AWS API Gateway gets Timeout or gives Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have used API Gateway for routing our actual apis which are written in `loopback`.

I have come across that API Gateway has default timeout of 29 seconds.

Our server is in production now, some apis are taking too much time, some giving errors and some are not working only.

So it is difficult to manager exactly which APIs are causing the issue.

I am looking for an automated solution, like Is it possible to detect APIs Timeout or errors, In API Gateway via some `lambda` function or `cloud watch` alerts.

Note that I want to send notification of the APIs that are getting timeout or causing error not all the apis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct integration with Slack from CloudWatch. Here is the architecture we follow.

> Cloudwatch --> SNS --> Lambda --> Slack

Send your alarms to SNS and subscribe to Lambda, then lambda can send it to slack. You can keep the slack generic for any alerts you receive from cloudwatch.

Also with Slack you can control delivering to multiple channels for different type of alerts.

The complete above implementation is documented here, should not take more than 10 minutes to complete everything.

https://read.acloud.guru/slack-notification-with-cloudwatch-alarms-lambda-6f2cc77b463a

Hope it helps.